# Dollar value changing fast and salary doesn't change

Tags: ethics, human-resources, salaried-pay, sri-lanka

US dollar is changing very fast in my country now. I'm working for a foreign company and I get a very satisfactory salary. But my consideration is as the US dollar is fluctuating rapidly, should I drop a email to HR division to point this out?

Foreign company might be paying for the employees by US dollars. But our salaries have defined(by the company in my country) in local currency. Therefore, even though the US dollar raised up, employee salary doesn't raise up . Many of my expenses are online ones. Therefore I face this impact hugely.

Is this something point out to HR division as a normal employee like me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will be part of the idea they had when they agreed to charge the client in dollars, but pay staff in local.  Something to think about/negotiate at the next job.

Comment: I work for a swiss company. The work I do and how they get paid in what currency is no concern of mine. I am contracted for a certain amount of local currency per month.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fact that the company is foreign-owned is irrelevant: you're being paid in local currency after all. Fluctuating exchange rates are not a valid reason to base salary negotiations on. If you feel you're not being paid enough, argue for a merit-based raise: your accomplishments and the value you added to the company in the past year(s).

If the US dollar crashed, would you appreciate having your wages cut in half as well?

Comment: The amount someone is being billed out to a client is definitely value added to the company.  Whatever the company is making when the "smoke clears" from the exchanger rate is fair game to base compensation.

Answer (score 12):

> Many of my expenses are online ones. Therefore I face this impact hugely.

I would think that you need to look at your online expenses rather than your salary. Your salary stays the same. It's unrealistic to ask for more because you like shopping online. That's basically the same as asking for a payrise because you have expensive tastes.

So my advice would be to mitigate against your online spending, because I doubt an employer wants to base your salary on the vagaries of an overseas currency.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my litmus test - can you get a better paying job some place else? If you can, then independent of what happens with the dollar you will get a better pay if you want to. If you can't, again regardless of what the dollar does you won't be able to get more pay. It is simple as that - the company will not on their own offer you more money just because of currency fluctuation. They very likely will take that as more profit.

Think this the other way - will they reduce your salary if the dollar weakens? I doubt it. So, when it comes to salary, you get paid what you negotiate, not what you deserve.

Answer (score 2):

You can send whatever you like, but don't expect it to have any effect. Your HR staff are just as aware of the dollar exchange rate as you are, and will either take that into account in any pay rises, or decide that it's your choice to spend your pay in venues where you are susceptible to exchange rate fluctuations.

Putting it another way: what would be your response if the currency fluctuations were going the other way and you received a mail from HR telling you your pay was being cut?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to have your salary be stable in terms of what spend on essentials, such as food, and any long term commitments, such as leases and loan repayments.

If the local currency is subject to hyper-inflation, you want to be paid in almost anything else.

Under more normal conditions, you are usually better off having your pay be in terms of the currency where you live. Otherwise, you could sign a lease on an apartment for an affordable fraction of your pay at the time of signing, and find it is unaffordable later, because of a change in exchange rates.